# Deleting the accepted answer

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Specifically this question [Bending knees in reverse hyperextension](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/37153/bending-knees-in-reverse-hyperextension)

Having read around the subject, I agree that Mike-DHSc's answer is correct and mine was taking more a physics view rather than an anatomy view of things.

If I now delete my answer, what happens? Or would I be better off editing it to point to Mike's answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Allow author of accepted answer to delete it in certain circumstances](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances)

[Is there a general rule for how to deal with your answer if you disagree with it later?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290077/is-there-a-general-rule-for-how-to-deal-with-your-answer-if-you-disagree-with-it)

Those are not specific, so I asked some more experienced SE moderators, and the general agreement is to do what you guys have done, edit and comment to the original poster to see if they will change their accepted answer.

The reasoning is that while your answer may be incorrect, it still has value, and may be useful to future visitors. I went ahead and left a comment for the OP to switch their acceptance if they would like. They are a semi-regular visitor, so they may see it soon.